# How to avoid unnecessary arguments when using optional generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

StateFunction has an optional (second) generic type - since it has a default value. The problem is that if I don't pass the second generic I still have to put `undefined` as an argument, even though I thought it will be optional at this point.

Making `args` optional using `args?` does help, but it forces to check for nulls even tough type isn't nullable.

I could also overload the function, but this isn't optimal as the real function I am using is pretty long.

Is there a real solution to make that argument disappear where the second generic isn't specified?

```js
interface StateFunctionAction<T, P> {
  (saved: T, args: P): void
}

const StateFunction = <T, P = undefined>(value : T, action: StateFunctionAction<T, P>) => {
  let saved = value;
  return (args : P) => action(saved, args);
}

const example1 = StateFunction<string>("Hello World", (saved) => console.log(saved))
example1(); // Help -> An argument for 'args' was not provided.

const example2 = StateFunction<string, number>("Hello World", (saved, n) => console.log(saved + " " + n))
example2(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `undefined` as default generic type use `void` instead. This will make the argument disappear.

```
const StateFunction = <T, P = void>(value : T, action: StateFunctionAction<T, P>) => {
  let saved = value;
  return (args : P) => action(saved, args);
}
```